# java servlet forwarding cookie

Tags: java, http, cookies

I want to develop a java servlet able to authenticate via HTTP protocol on an other server. That server sends back a cookie to my servlet and i want to forward back to the browser that cookie and redirect the browser to another url.

I can not figure out how to intercept and sendBack cookie via servlet.

Do you have any suggestions on method or class to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't catch what you mean 'intercept cookie', but sending back cookie is quite simple just add cookie to response object.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", value);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

And then forward your request:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response)
```

Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: ... but then the cookie is set for the original domain, not the other domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course illegal; tampering with a cookie of another domain.

Java has good support for Open-ID, which might happen to be usable in your case.

In the case of a java site the session ID may both be used as cookie and as URL parameter (JSESSIONID often). In that case you could use the JSESSIONID parameter.

Often a site has a login with a continue to some page (something like login.html?url=...).
In that case you might try redirecting to login-form GET-submit.
To find that URL: call a bookmarked URL being logged out.

I have some doubts that there is such a loop hole though.